# FileNotFoundException :File file:/path/to/file/in.txt does not exist or the user running Flink has insufficient permissions to access it

Tags: python, apache-flink

I'm trying to test Wordcount classic example using flink and python batch api.
My problem is that after modifying the data source from env.from_elements() to env.read_text() (for a bigger test case), an error occurs. The Following code, depicts my implementation.

```
[...]
if __name__ == "__main__":
env = get_environment()
input_file = 'file:///workfile.txt/'

if len(sys.argv) != 1 and len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit("Usage: ./bin/pyflink.sh WordCount[ - <text path> <result path>]")

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    data = env.read_text(sys.argv[1])
else:
    #data = env.from_elements("hello","world","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello","car","tree","data","hello")
    data = env.read_text(input_file)

result = data \
    .flat_map(Tokenizer()) \
    .group_by(1) \
    .reduce_group(Adder(), combinable=True) \

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    result.write_csv(sys.argv[2])
else:
    result.output()
[...]
```

Executing the above code, throws a file permission error. More specifically, the following message

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Creating the input splits caused an error: File file:/workfile.txt does not exist or the user running Flink ('user') has insufficient permissions to access it.

PS: Searched for a solution, but couldn't find something. If this problem is already solved, i would appreciate a redirection.

Comment: can you share your `get_environment` ?

Comment: The environment contains no information, it's just an API.

Comment: thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that "workfile.txt" is supposed to be a relative path. However, you cannot have relative files with a scheme ("file:///").

Please provide the full absolute path and it should work.

Note that relative paths don't work in general with the Python API as we execute the script in a temporary location.

Comment: Yeah, the absolute path is the solution. But for some reason, i thought that absolute path is the path from where i call flink's jobmanager. Then i tried the path from /home/to/flink/txt/path and it works fine.